Windows API BitBlt fails for some resolutions
I've made a simple program in C++ that captures the screen using BitBlt from the Windows API and saves it to a file, and some resolution seem to give memory errors, and I cant seem to find the pattern/problem in my code.
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

BYTE* CaptureScreen(int x, int y, int width, int height);

bool CaptureScreenAndSaveToFile(int x, int y, int width, int height, const char* filename) {
    BYTE* imageData = CaptureScreen(x, y, width, height);
    if (imageData == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    // Open file for writing
    std::ofstream outFile(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!outFile.is_open()) {
        delete[] imageData; // Free allocated memory
        return false;
    }

    // Write BMP file header
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHeader;
    bmpFileHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; // 'BM'
    bmpFileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + width * height * 3; // Total file size
    bmpFileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmpFileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); // Offset to pixel data

    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpFileHeader), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));

    // Write BMP info header
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader;
    bmpInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = 24; // 24 bits per pixel (RGB)
    bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0; // Size of the pixel data (can be set to 0 for BI_RGB compression)
    bmpInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmpInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpInfoHeader), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

    // Write image data
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(imageData), width * height * 3);

    // Close the file
    outFile.close();

    // Free allocated memory
    delete[] imageData;

    return true;
}

BYTE* CaptureScreen(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    BYTE* result = nullptr; // Initialize the result pointer to nullptr

    HDC hdcTemp, hdc;
    BYTE* bitPointer;

    hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    if (hdc != NULL)
    {
        hdcTemp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        if (hdcTemp != NULL)
        {
            BITMAPINFO bitmap;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bitmap.bmiHeader);
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height; // Negative height to ensure the bitmap is top-down
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

            HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdcTemp, &bitmap, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&bitPointer, NULL, NULL);
            if (hBitmap != NULL)
            {
                HBITMAP hPrevBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcTemp, hBitmap); // Added explicit cast

                BitBlt(hdcTemp, 0, 0, width, height, hdc, x, y, SRCCOPY); // Use x, y, width, height
                // Allocate memory on the heap and copy the buffer
                result = new BYTE[width * height * 3];
                if (result != nullptr) {
                    memcpy(result, bitPointer, width * height * 3);
                }

                // Select and delete objects
                SelectObject(hdcTemp, hPrevBitmap);
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            }

            DeleteDC(hdcTemp);
        }

        ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    CaptureScreenAndSaveToFile(125, 125, 35, 35, "Hello.png");
}

I've noticed that for some resolutions, the screenshot saved is unviewable, and when I try to directly access the bytebuffer, an error about inaccessible memory is thrown.
Here are the resolutions I tried that failed:

Anything under (W: 36, H: 36)
And (W: 255, H: 255)

I'm sure there are many more widths and heights that "fails" but I cant seem to find the pattern/problem here. Any help would be appreciated.

every scan line must be 4 bytes align. so ((3*width+3)&~3)

Can you please elaborate?
Edit: I figured it out, tysm.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440672/bmp-file-line-padding-issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601365/padding-in-24-bits-rgb-bitmap

A bug that can easily be avoided by not trying to write a BMP image file but let the Windows Imaging Component do it for you instead.

As @RbMm said and the threads @drescherjm sent,
This is how many bytes each row of the bitmap is calculated;
Grayscale image (biBitCount=8)Color image (biBitCount=24)
bmpWidth is the width of the bitmap, i.e. how many pixel blocks there are per row
If you are shaping, (n) divided by (n+i) is equal to 0, (n and i are both natural numbers)
The number of bytes per line of stored image data is a multiple of 4
Therefore, +3 is for fear of not meeting the multiple of 4
If it's a multiple of 4, the result is the same as if it weren't +3
If it is not a multiple of 4, the result is advanced by 1 place.
/4*4 divided by four multiplied by four puts the data in multiples of 4.
If it is not a multiple of 4, the remainder will be reduced.
For example, in the case of shaping, 17/4 = 4 (normal is 4 and 1/4), and the computer directly calculates that it is equal to 4
Multiply by four to equal 16
That is, classify 17 as a multiple of 4 = 16;
